# Session on SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I just want to ask if how to establish a session on sql server.
Example scenario is that when one user is currently accessing the column on a table the other user cannot access the value(data) on it or in other words each user cannot transact simultaneously? Is it possible?

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense because it uses non-existent terms or existing ones in the wrong way. What do you mean "session"? There's no such term in databases. You may mean "transaction" but that's *not* needed to ensure integrity. There's no problem with multiple users reading the same data or even read/write scenarios. What is your *actual* problem? Why do you need that you have to restrict access to a single user at a time?

Comment: The wording of the question is confusing. Do you want to restrict access to a single user, or do you think that access is restricted and want to allow multiple users? You can use different transaction levels or even snapshot isolation to fix either problem. You can use optimistic concurrency on the client to avoid transactions. But you have to explain *which* problem you want solved

Comment: The actual problem is that there are multiple users which is given on a system. I am just trying to prevent to access the column by multiple user. Say for example when user 1 is currently accessing the value on table A column 1 the other user cannot view that value when he/she is trying to access that column on table A.

Comment: Why? Databases are supposed to serve multiple users. There's nothing wrong with multiple users reading the same row/column. What is the *actual business problem* you are trying to solve? Are you trying to force some kind of business workflow, versioning or checkout functinoality, and think that some sort of transaction locking is the easy answer? It isn't, there are other ways to do this

Comment: Yes ideally it is. But is part of business workflow. Here is the problem: "Receiving of Items in Purchase Order". When user 1 is currently receiving the PO#1 the user 2 cannot view that PO#. The reason is that it can cause multiple receiving of items that i just want to prevent.

Comment: **Please update the question text with the *actual* problem description.** Transactions and locking are *not* meant to implement business worfklows, in any database system. That's the job of SQL views, stored procedures  and functions. You can add fields or separate tables with the versioning status of each record, use views that filter checked-out results, stored procedures to implement the checkin/checkout functionality

Comment: For example, the problem statement identifies the business state of an order. It can be received, in review, finalized etc. You probably need a state diagram to describe the allowed transitions already. You need either SQL statements or better, stored procedures that allow only the correct transitions. You can use vies or functions to return orders in a specific state. People can't answer the question though as long as the question asks a different thing

Comment: is there a solution or query on sql server to fetch the what specific rows or column in a table is currently using?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't know *your* business requirements. Besides, what does "currently using" mean? A query for a single row takes milliseconds, yet a user can stare into a screen for hours. Which means, you also need a timeout to release such records if the user forgets to check them in. Now, your state machine has timeout attributes.

Comment: **Please update the question!**. I can't keep describing workflow implementations in comments that can be deleted at any time, nor do I want my answer to sound like I am answering the wrong question. A **lot** of people have implemented workflows and state machines over databases, but none of them will realize this is a relevant question

Comment: I min currently accessing on the database

Comment: Which as I said, won't help you at all. A row is "accessed" when a query accesses it and that takes milliseconds. Once the query finishes, the row isn't "accessed" by anything. You probably mean "which users display this record", which has nothing to do with the database. It's a UI operation.

Comment: okay thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the locking properties of the connection you make to the database. By default the table gets locked I believe, you should be able to overrule this.

Comment: This is wrong. You are confusing transactions with locks. The table doesn't "get locked" by default either. There are no locking properties on the connection. According to the transaction isolation mode, the server locks certain objects, eg the row that's being read or written to.